# Shell script is printing parameeter without passing to it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, parameters

I am calling a script2.sh from script1.sh without passing parameter. But I am passing parameter to script1.sh. I am trying to print first parameter of script2.sh.

**script1.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
PRM1=$1
source script2.sh
```

**script2.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
PRM1=$1
echo "$PRM1"
```

**output is**

```
# source script1.sh hello
#hello
#
```

But **Ideally**

```
# source script1.sh hello

#
```

**Can any one tell me why script2.sh is taking script1.sh parameter as it's parameter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [bash(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> #### SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
>
> ```
> source filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> Read  and execute commands from *filename* in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from *filename*.  If *filename* does not contain a slash, file names in `PATH` are used to find the directory containing *filename*.  The file searched for in `PATH` need not be executable.  When `bash` is not in posix mode, the current directory is searched if no file is found in `PATH`.   If  the  `sourcepath`  option  to  the  `shopt`  builtin command is turned off, the `PATH` is not searched.  **If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when *filename* is executed.  Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.**  The return status is the status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if *filename* is not found or cannot be read.

Comment: So, how to overcome this. is there any workaround. Because I want to pass parameter once, another time I will not pass. How to handle this situation ?

Comment: One solution is to call `shift` in script1.sh after assigning `PRM1=$1`. That will discard the first positional parameter to your script.  Or call `set --` to discard all the positional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving your script1.sh any argument as it is expecting one.  (A small note, I always close the white space in this line: `#!/bin/bash` - not `#! /bin/bash`).  In your script1.sh, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PRM1=$1
./script2.sh $PRM1
```

Answer (score 1):

pass junk as parameter. so that the positional parameter will replace with it.